# MIPS with Mars sim. - how to read a value from a keyboard input automatically (i.e. - no pressing enter to get the value)

Tags: assembly, io, mips

Is there a specific syscall or something I am missing in order to accomplish this?

Comment: This isn't really MIPS-specific ?!  If you're running Linux on it, you need to use what's called "non-canonical input processing" (to get a character at a time instead of waiting for a newline). An example can be found in the Linux Serial programming FAQ, http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO.html#AEN102

Comment: @FrankH. Err, I mean, I am using a MIPS simulator (Mars) and need to be able to do this.  Sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use syscall #12 to read a character.
See [the MARS syscall sheet](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) for further details.
Here goes an example that reads a character from console and prints the next ASCII code char

```
loop:  
  li   $v0, 12       
  syscall            # Read Character

  addiu $a0, $v0, 1  # $a0 gets the next char

  li   $v0, 11       
  syscall            # Write Character

  b loop
  nop
```