# How to detect arrow keys in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, io, mips, mars-simulator

I'd like to read which arrow keys are pressed on the keyboard, to use them as controls for a game. I found related questions, to read a character ([MIPS with Mars sim. - how to read a value from a keyboard input automatically (i.e. - no pressing enter to get the value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065189/mips-with-mars-sim-how-to-read-a-value-from-a-keyboard-input-automatically-i)) or to do exactly what I need to do in x86 ([How to detect arrow keys in 16-bit DOS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939449/how-to-detect-arrow-keys-in-16-bit-dos-code)), but I'm still a bit confused on how to implement it in MIPS.

Comment: Are you using MARS?  If so you can tag with mars-simulator.

Comment: Not sure this is possible in MARS with its toy system-call interface and very simplistic "terminal".